# Is there any shortcut to preview procedure/function definition

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I once saw a professional guy doing this: in a normal SQL query window, select any procedure/function name, and stroke a key combination, then the definition of this object is right there in **query result grid**, then he can just copy the resulting text to an editor to review it.

I'm regretting not asking him, so I'm asking here right now, hopefully, someone would know how to do that, thanks!

BTW, he was using SQL Server Management Studio, don't know which version.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for `sp_helptext` ?

```
sp_helptext 'procedure/function name'
```

And then just press `F5` to view destination of `procedure/function name` in query result grid.

If you want to see `OBJECT` schema then use `alt + f1` combination.

Comment: The OP's colleague may have configured a shortcut key for this https://i.stack.imgur.com/68Myj.png

Comment: @MartinSmith. . .  Will display `OBJECT` schema not the Definition which may OP looking for.

Comment: yes but you can type `sp_helptext` into any free cell to use that as a shortcut. Or change the defaults

Comment: hey, @YogeshSharma & @martin, I successfully created a shortcut to use `sp_helptext` command as a shortcut, both of you are a great pro! Thank You. BTW `alt + f1` as `sp_help` is quite useful!

Answer (score 1):

Redgate SQLPrompt, a third party plugin for SSMS, has also similar functionality. When mouse cursor is on top of any object a pop-up window appears with a definition of the object:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, will try it once my SQL tasks getting more complicated, after all, it requires a purchase :)